# Dashed line path following the moving images in D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, path

Here i'm working on moving images dynamically with random x and y, inside a zooming & dragging SVG. Now I want to append dashed path following these moving images. Similar to the image below:

[image]

I found a [D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/cloudshapes/5661984), where a dotted path following the mouse. I tried the same code to create a path for one image for the time being. Instead of mouse X & Y coordinates, i used the random X and Y values of moving image.

```
var pt = [];
pt.push(randomX);pt.push(randomY);
tick(pt);

function tick(pt) {

  // push a new data point onto the back
  ptdata.push(pt);

  // Redraw the path:
  path.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d);})

  // If more than 100 points, drop the old data pt off the front
  if (ptdata.length > npoints) {
      ptdata.shift();
  }
}
```

But the result was thick lines displayed in a disorder manner on top of the background image (Grass Texture image). Please check out the [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/NayanaDas/1st7xjr7/1/) and please suggest a way to create dashed line path for the moving images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: **"result was thick lines displayed"**
Reason you need to give `fill none`

```
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 2,5;
}
```

You had not given the style for the line.

Second problem:  **disorder manner on top of the background image**

The reason is you running the time interval in a span of 50 millisecond,
but transition to move the image from point 1 to point 2 is 6000 millisecond thus the images are not able to move to its new calculated random position.

In short the anomaly is because you creating new points in 50 milliseconds but want to transition into the new place in 6000 milliseconds, so the points are not able to move to its position.

I have corrected the time interval to create points to 1 second.
Also i have changed the transition time of image to move in 100 milliseconds.

Working code [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/52v8yvk1/1/)

Comment: See you creating new random points in `setInterval` function, you can delay the point creation from 1000 millisecond to 2000 millisecond

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have one doubt, its bit confusing when the movement become so fast, so How can i slow down the movement and how can i add path for all other images? please explain.

Comment: Can u please explain, how to  add path for all other images?

Comment: In my Fiddle Line No 107 -111 i am making random point and adding it into the array. same randomPoint is used below in the if else block to update the image position.

Comment: Sir, sorry for my ignorance, but when i slow down the movement , the line moving in some other place and images are moving in another place. Actually what i need was different line path following these images, just like the image shown above in my question. Is that possible?

Comment: @Nayana the image shows 3 lines in your case you just have one line. May be you need to make 3 different lines. each tracking one image.
currently you just have one line tracking all images.

Comment: Yes, there is only one line. is it possible to add lines for each image, moving along with the images?

Comment: Yes excatly, i need each tracking lines for each image, moving along with it , is that possible?

Comment: yeah possible to do that

Comment: How to add it? is it ok to add the following code : var pt = [];  pt.push(randomX);pt.push(randomY);  tick(pt);  , in each if loop such as if (icons[i] == "user") to create different path for each image

Comment: I have made a sample of three paths https://fiddle.jshell.net/pyxg3pu1/ you can make it better.